# google.maps.places.Autocomplete localization

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete

In my app I'm using `google.maps.places.Autocomplete.getPlace()` in order to get info such the name of a city, the problem is that the informations retrieved are localized according to the "`language`" parameter passed via querystring when importing the library, instead I would like to have them always in english, while preserving localization in the autocomplete and the rendered map (that is, if the user is italian he will see for example "**Venezia**" in the UI, but in my client-side api I will get "**Venice**")... how can I do?

Answer (score 4):

Okay, I found it here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics#Localization

So basically you need to provide `language` parameter when loading Google API:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?language=en">
```